# Google Apps script timeout after return;

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

for my company we started automizing the naming creation of product. I wrote function for every category and normally they are working just fine. But unfortunally for 2 categorys the code should work but after the `return;` instruction or the code just ending plain the code runs empty for 1:34 min and the errors with a timeout. I tried a lot of thing, like copying the code and the sheets to another Gsheet but nothing worked. I checked the data for the categorys line by line for 10000 lines and everything is loaded and formatted right and even if not it should still work. Like i said the code runs to the last line of data in the sheet.

Here the end of the code (as I cant show the code in whole):

```
var namelength = name.replace(/\s+$/, '').split(" ");
Logger.log('Name length: ' + namelength.length);

var colmissing = "Collectionname missing";
var oneword = "one worded name";

if (collectionNames[sku] != "" && collectionNames[sku] != " " && collectionNames[sku]) {
  colmissing = " ";
  Logger.log('Collection name is missing');
}

if (namelength.length == 1) {
  nameword = true;
  Logger.log('Name is one word');
} else if (namelength.length == 0) {
  name = "naming creation not possible";
  Logger.log('Naming creation not possible');
} else {
  oneword = " ";
  Logger.log('Name is more than one word');
}

sheet.getRange(i + 1, 11).setValue(name);
Logger.log('Set name in cell: ' + (i + 1) + ', 11');

sheet.getRange(i + 1, 12).setValue(colmissing);
Logger.log('Set collection missing status in cell: ' + (i + 1) + ', 12');

sheet.getRange(i + 1, 13).setValue(oneword);
Logger.log('Set one word status in cell: ' + (i + 1) + ', 13');

if (i === data.length - 1) {
  return;
  Logger.log("Reached the end of the data. Exiting...");
  return;
}
}
}
```

The console loge is like this in the end:

```
2:56:06 PM  Info    Name length: 1
2:56:06 PM  Info    Name is one word
2:56:06 PM  Info    Set name in cell: 7458, 11
2:56:06 PM  Info    Set collection missing status in cell: 7458, 12
2:56:06 PM  Info    Set one word status in cell: 7458, 13
2:57:40 PM  Error   
Service Spreadsheets timed out while accessing document with id 1DayQATe6mQMpRNLJstYWgPJgOC4-zDRuTdVMLgTzKm4.
```

The Code should end after `return;` but in the end the only thing that happens is that I get a very early time out after around 2 min of code run and not 6 min like apps script should run at least.

Comment: What row does you data begin on? And can we see the  beginning of the code where data arrays are defined?  If not then I'd recommend writing a [mcve] with emphasis on minimal.  I say that because most of the time where I do that I end up figuring out the problem on my own.

Comment: Try if( i === (data.length-1) ) {.  It may be operator precedence.